# passing a variable to a scss 'mixin' worked in rails 3.0 but not in 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass

I am ugrading an app from rails 3.0 to 3.2 there is a problem with some of my scss code. stylin.css contains:

```
/*
= require_self
= require_tree .
*/
```

stylin.css.scss contains:

```
@import "palette";
@import "round";
@import "html_elements";
@import "graph";
@import "menu";
@import "button";
@import "pop_up";
@import "basic_abrev";
```

When the styling.css is updated 'palette' is imported but nothing else is imported. Consequently, I get the following error when loading the first page:

```
Undefined mixin 'round_corners'
```

I think it is because the top of 'round.css.scss' includes the following:

```
@mixin round_corners($radius: 8px) {
  border-radius: $radius;
  -moz-border-radius: $radius;
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
}
```

If no variable passed the default would be 8px. In the following case '20px' is passed to the mixin.

```
@include round_corners(20px);
```

This worked in 3.0. Is this no longer possible? If not, I'll have to create numerous mixins or discontinue using the mixing / include feature for rounding corners.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the Sass @import rule instead of these Sprockets directives. Using Sprockets directives all Sass files exist within their own scope, making variables or mixins only available within the document they were defined in.

I found this [here](https://github.com/petebrowne/sprockets-sass):

When using Sprockets 2.x with Sass you will eventually run into a pretty big issue. //= require directives will not allow Sass mixins, variables, etc. to be shared between files.

Found this [here](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails):

Sprockets provides some directives that are placed inside of comments called require, require_tree, and require_self. DO NOT USE THEM IN YOUR SASS/SCSS FILES. They are very primitive and do not work well with Sass files. Instead, use Sass's native @import directive which sass-rails has customized to integrate with the conventions of your rails projects.

When I deleted this (sprockets commands) from the stylin.css.scss file, everything worked.

```
/*
= require_self
= require_tree .
*/
```